# Addin variables upstream to compute hessian matrix

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, gradient, hessian

starting from the following "graph_first"

```
graph_first = tf.Graph()

with graph_first.as_default():  
    v = tf.get_variable(name='v', shape=[2], dtype=tf.float64)  
    x = v[:1]  
    y = v[1:]
```

it is easy to obtain the following 'graph_unique':

```
graph_unique = tf.Graph()

with graph_unique.as_default():  
    v = tf.get_variable(name='v', shape=[2], dtype=tf.float64)  
    x = v[:1]  
    y = v[1:]  
    c = tf.add(x, y, name='c')  
    gra = tf.gradients([c], [v])
```

Indeed, it is enough to add the the variables c and gra to make 
'graph_first' equivalent to 'graph_unique'. Assuming the definition above,

```
with graph_first.as_default():  
    c = tf.add(x,y, name='c')  
    gra = tf.gradients([c], [v])
```

Suppose now, that we need to start from the following 'graph_second',
instead:

```
graph_second = tf.Graph()

with graph_second.as_default():  
    x = tf.get_variable(name='x', shape=[1], dtype=tf.float64)  
    y = tf.get_variable(name='y', shape=[1], dtype=tf.float64)  
    c = tf.add(x, y, name='c')  
    gra = tf.gradients([c], [x,y])
```

How can we recover a graph equivalent to 'graph_unique'? 
In other words: tf allows to very easily add variables DOWNSTREAM in a graph.
Is it possible in some way to add them also UPSTREAM? 
The idea is to make all trainable variables in a graph to become dependent 
on a new, single, bigger, initial one.
It would be crucial for me, that both gradient and hessian work correctly.

Thanx a lot!